# Gulp + Less + Minify CSS error: concat multiple Less files?

Tags: css, gulp, less, gulp-less, gulp-clean-css

How do you concat multiple Less files?

For instance, I have `functions.less` with all the functions that I want to use them in the `style.less`:

functions.less:

```
.rotate (@deg) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(@deg * 1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(@deg * 1deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(@deg * 1deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(@deg * 1deg);
}
```

style.less:

```
.button {
    .rotate (@deg: 90);
}
```

gulpfile.js:

```
// Task to compile less.
gulp.task('compile-less', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'stylesheets/*.less'
  ])
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(concat('compiled.css'))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('stylesheets'))
})

// Task to minify css.
gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'stylesheets/compiled.css'
  ])
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}))
  .pipe(concat('bundle.min.css'))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  .pipe(livereload())
})
```

I will get:

> Potentially unhandled rejection [2] No matching definition was found
>   for `.rotate (@deg: 90)` in file /var/www/.../style.less line no. 107

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I get this errors sometimes when I use `@import`:

```
undefined:1



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at loadInputSourceMapFromLocalUri (/var/www/.../node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/apply-source-maps.js:177:15)
    at extractInputSourceMapFrom (/var/www/.../node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/apply-source-maps.js:116:17)
    at fetchAndApplySourceMap (/var/www/.../node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/apply-source-maps.js:79:10)
    at doApplySourceMaps (/var/www/.../node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/apply-source-maps.js:57:14)
    at applySourceMaps (/var/www/.../node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/apply-source-maps.js:33:5)
    at Object.callback (/var/www/.../node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/read-sources.js:25:12)
    at doInlineImports (/var/www/.../node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/read-sources.js:200:25)
    at Object.callback (/var/www/.../node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/read-sources.js:324:14)
    at doInlineImports (/var/www/.../node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/read-sources.js:200:25
```

**EDIT 2:**

Obviously it is `gulp-clean-css` that is causing the problem:

```
// CSS compilation.
var concat = require('gulp-concat')
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css')
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css') // optional

gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'stylesheets/style.css'
  ])
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  // .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}))
  .pipe(concat('bundle.min.css'))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  .pipe(livereload())
})
```

No error if I remove that line but then I does not minify the css anymore if I do.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 3:**

Entire content in gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload')

// JavaScript development.
var browserify = require('browserify')
var babelify = require('babelify')
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')

// Less compilation.
var less = require('gulp-less')

// CSS compilation.
var concat = require('gulp-concat')
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css')
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css') // optional

// HTML compilation.
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin')
var path = require('path')
var foreach = require('gulp-foreach')

// Task to compile js.
gulp.task('compile-js', function () {
  return browserify({
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    entries:  ['./javascripts/app.js'],
    debug: true
  })
  .transform('babelify', {
    presets: ['es2015', 'es2017', 'react'],
    plugins: [

      // Turn async functions into ES2015 generators
      // https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/
      "transform-async-to-generator"
    ]
  })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.min.js'))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  .pipe(livereload())
})

// Task to compile less.
gulp.task('compile-less', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'stylesheets/*.less'
  ])
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('stylesheets'))
})

// Task to minify css.
gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'stylesheets/style.css'
  ])
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}))
  .pipe(concat('bundle.min.css'))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  .pipe(livereload())
})

// Loop each html.
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach
gulp.task('minify-html', function () {
  return gulp.src('*.html')
    .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file){
      // Get the filename.
      // https://github.com/mariusGundersen/gulp-flatMap/issues/4
      // https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_p_ext
      var name = path.basename(file.path)
      return stream
        .pipe(htmlmin({
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true
        }))
        .pipe(concat('min.' + name))
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
})

// Task to copy fonts to dist.
gulp.task('compile-fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'fonts/*',
    'node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.*',
    'node_modules/foundation-icon-fonts/foundation-icons.*',
  ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts/'))
})

// Task to copy images to dist.
gulp.task('compile-images', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'images/*',
    'node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/images/*',
  ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images/'))
})

// Task to watch less & css changes.
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('javascripts/*.js', ['compile-js'])  // Watch all the .js files, then run the js task
  gulp.watch('stylesheets/*.less', ['compile-less'])  // Watch all the .less files, then run the less task
  gulp.watch('stylesheets/*.css', ['minify-css'])  // Watch all the .css files, then run the css task
  gulp.watch('stylesheets/*.css', ['compile-fonts'])  // Watch all the .css files, then run the font task
  gulp.watch('stylesheets/*.css', ['compile-images'])  // Watch all the .css files, then run the image task
})

// Development:
// Task when running `gulp` from terminal.
gulp.task('default', ['watch'])

// Production:
// Task when running `gulp build` from terminal.
gulp.task('build', ['minify-css', 'compile-fonts', 'compile-js', 'minify-html'])
```

Comment: That's what [`@import`](http://lesscss.org/#importing)s are for (though can you concatenate you less fies just by putting a `concat` task *before* the `less` task). Aside of that - you really need to discover autoprefixing tools and forget about the vendor-prefixing-mixins-nightmare forever. (Nobody uses such things for years by now).

Comment: @seven-phases-max i did that already but it gives me errors.

Comment: *gives me errors* is not something one could help with (what errors?) It's not hard to guess though that what you get is something [like this](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-less/issues/278). Try to search through [gulp-less] QAs here at SO - I'm pretty sure there're tones of duplicate issues (as "compiling all files instead of the only file of interest" is the most common mistake in gulp/grunt).

Comment: @seven-phases-max please see my edit above. I get that sometimes.

Comment: That's looks like quite exotic error. Note the error itself comes from `clean-css` modulle (which is applied to the already compiled CSS thus having nothing to do with `gulp-less` or Less in general). The error mentions "imports" but that's regular CSS imports (`clean-css` tries to process and fails because of some source-map fail) not the imports you do in your Less code. I'd suggest to ask at some clean-css trackers (`clean-css` itself or its corresponding `gulp` plugin).

Comment: @seven-phases-max yes it is `clean-css` causing the error. see my edit 2 above.

Comment: How do you call those tasks?  I want to see that too.

Comment: @Mark please see my edit 3. thanks.

Comment: Do you get the errors when running the build task only?

Comment: @Mark both - even the watch task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is create a master less file and import all your less files.

So create, for example a file called **master.less**. Then edit this file by adding the follow instruction:

```
 @import "functions.less";
 @import "styles.less";
```

And thats it. Then the gulp-less does the rest!! :) It compiles al the code in one single css file.

My suggestion for your task is (this is the code i have in my project startup):

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
        postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
        less = require('gulp-less'),
        autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
        concat = require('gulp-concat'),
        cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync');


    gulp.task('less', function () {
        var processors = [
            autoprefixer,
            cssnano
        ];
        gulp.src(config.paths.less.src)
            .pipe(less())
            .pipe(postcss(processors))
            .pipe(concat('bundle.min.css'))
            .pipe(cssnano())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
    });
```

Comment: Yes 100% sure about that.

Comment: But are you working with less or css? I need to know that to try to help you!! :)

Comment: I added an idea for your code. Then you just need to add the sourcemaps pipe.

Comment: Thank you. Importing the less files into a master less file works actually.